# How to use indexes when trying to make null values come last?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 and I am trying to retrieve all rows ordered by some col1 with null values coming last. As of now I am using this kind o query:

```
select * from table order by row1 is null, row1 asc
```

As there are many rows in my table, the query worked quite slowly, so I decided to create an index on table(row1).

After creating the index it extremely improved the speed of queries like:

```
select * from table order by row1 asc
```

However sqlite doesn't seem to use that index with "order by col1 is null" type of queries.

Why sqlite, based on that index, can't just move rows with null values to the end?
Is there any way I can make null values come last without the need to evaluate every row every time again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite 3.8.12 will support expressions in indexes:

```
> CREATE TABLE t(x);
> CREATE INDEX tnx ON T(x IS NULL, x);
> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY x IS NULL, x;
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE t USING COVERING INDEX tnx
```

In earlier versions, you can split the query into two subqueries, each of which can use an index:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM MyTable
      WHERE row1 IS NOT NULL
      ORDER BY row1)
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE row1 IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a conditional in `order by`.

```
select * from table 
order by case when row1 is null then 1 else 0 end, row1
```

The default ordering is `ascending`. Hence `asc` has been omitted from the query above.

Comment: This does not answer the question (how to use an index for sorting).